Fields with the 'declare' modifier cannot be initialized here, but only in the constructor
I don't even know where to begin or what to look for with this one.
I'm upgrading an old React, Node, Express full-stack application, and one of the steps I'm taking is adding TypeScript. The project still uses WebPack and Babel, and I've upgraded those, but I don't have the knowledge or time to replace it with something else. In the process of the upgrade, I've read that using the babel-loader to transform TypeScript is preferable over ts-loader. That's fine, as long as it works. However, I'm also trying to upgrade Sequelize and implement sequelize-typescript for more declarative models. Trying to compile it though, I get a strange error I don't understand, as I've otherwise followed all the directions I've read.
(ETA: This does work if I'm using ts-loader, so it's something specific to Babel and/or its configuration. It seems like there should be a way to get babel-loader to support the same compilation as ts-loader if people are recommending it over ts-loader.)
The error is:
ERROR in ./lib/models/payment-typed.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/chris/code/ps-client/lib/models/payment-typed.ts: Fields with the 'declare' modifier cannot be initialized here, but only in the constructor
  12 | })
  13 | export class PaymentTyped extends Model {
> 14 |   @Column({
     |   ^
  15 |     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  16 |     allowNull: false,
  17 |     autoIncrement: true,
    at File.buildCodeFrameError (/Users/chris/code/ps-client/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:195:12)
...

The code it's trying to compile is:
import { Column, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'

@Table({
  createdAt: 'CreatedOn',
  modelName: 'Payment',
  timestamps: true,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'Payment',
  updatedAt: 'UpdatedOn',
  hasTrigger: true
})
export class PaymentTyped extends Model {
  @Column({
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  })
  declare ID: number
...

And the portion of the config that I think is relevant is:
...
export const BabelPresets = (envPreset) => [
  ['@babel/preset-env', envPreset],
  [
    '@babel/preset-react',
    {
      runtime: 'automatic'
    }
  ],
  [
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    {
      onlyRemoveTypeImports: true,
      allowNamespaces: true,
      dts: true,
      allowDeclareFields: true
    }
  ]
]

export const JavaScriptRules = (envPreset) => ({
  test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: BabelPresets(envPreset),
      plugins: [
        // https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#typescript-compiler-options
        'babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata',
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { version: '2023-11' }],
        [
          'babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes',
          { mapUnknownReferenceTypesToAny: true, strict: true }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
})
...

I don't even really know how to debug or research this. Google searches come up with seemingly completely unrelated and irrelevant stuff.
What can I change in my configuration or code to make this or something like this work?
Thanks

In your code, you are trying to use a property decorator(@column) on a field declared with declare. In Typescript, declare fields can only be initialized in the constructor, which is why you're seeing the error.
Solution:
Remove the declare modifier, and just define the property normally:
@Column({
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  })
  ID: number


Thank you for that, I kinda figured that would be a solution, but the Sequelize TypeScript documentation specifically says to use declare... though, admittedly, II don't remember why. I think probably because the field is supposed to be "artificial" and that the decorator generates the mappings and the declared property is there for typing... So, I have a solution, though, I'm not sure I'll still get the results I want. I'll keep searching but I can do this in the meantime, thank you.
ETA: Also, as I mentioned, it works in ts-loader but not babel-loader, so I might go back to that too.

To add to my response, the documentation for Sequelize says I must use declare so TypeScript doesn't emit the property.
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/#usage
"Important: You must use declare on your class properties typings to ensure TypeScript does not emit those class properties. See Caveat with Public Class Fields"
So I'm not sure why it says to do that if it's not allowed.
